# Creating HTML list from input array using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

Though I have seen similar questions here with solutions, yet I was not able to figure out the problem with my code. Can someone please help look into it and tell me what I'm not doing right. 
I am trying to add user input to the list using array functions. I want to already have 3 elements in the array before the user input and later remove the added inputs with another array method. but first to add the inputs has been my challenge. I have added my code for view.

```
    var domTarget = id => {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};
var UnsortedTrees = ["spruce", "pine", "cedar"];
let ordered = document.createElement("ol");
domTarget("tree-display").appendChild(ordered);
UnsortedTrees.forEach(Unsortedtree => {
  let listOfTrees = document.createElement("li");
  ordered.appendChild(listOfTrees);
  listOfTrees.innerHTML += Unsortedtree;
});

const frontAdd = () => {
  console.log(UnsortedTrees);
  let userInput = domTarget("array-input").value;
  var isValid = true;
  if (userInput === "") {
    alert("Please enter a tree name");
    isValid = false;
  }
  if (userInput) {
    UnsortedTrees.push(userInput);
    domTarget("tree-display").reset();
    let ordered = document.createElement("ol");
    domTarget("tree-display").appendChild(ordered);
    UnsortedTrees.forEach(Unsortedtree => {
      let listOfTrees = document.createElement("li");
      ordered.appendChild(listOfTrees);
      listOfTrees.innerHTML += Unsortedtree;
    });
  }
};

window.onload = () => {
   domTarget("front-add").onclick = frontAdd;
};
```

Comment: If possible, could you add your html too to make a working snippet please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactored your code a little bit. Would this be what you mean?

```js
(() => {
  const byId = id => document.querySelector(`#${id}`);
  const ordered = byId("treeList");
  const appendListItem = (orderedList, itemTxt) => {
    let listItem = document.createElement("li");
    listItem.textContent = itemTxt;
    orderedList.appendChild(listItem);
  };
  const addItem = () => {
    const inputEl = byId("array-input");
    const val = inputEl.value.trim();
  
    if (!val) { return alert("Please enter a tree name"); }

    UnsortedTrees.push(val);
    appendListItem(ordered, val);
    inputEl.value = "";
  };
  
  // create initial
  let UnsortedTrees = ["spruce", "pine", "cedar"];
  UnsortedTrees.forEach(item => appendListItem(ordered, item));
    
  // add button handling
  byId("addItem").addEventListener("click", addItem);
})();
```

```html
<div id="tree-display">
  <ol id="treeList"></ol>
</div>
<input id="array-input" type="text" placeholder="type a tree name"> 
<button id="addItem">Add</button>
```

Comment: perfect...It worked, exactly what I wanted...I was actually thinking I could get it done with pure Js without using query selector, But I think this appears neater.

Comment: However, I would still like to know if this can be solved with pure JavaScript only and  without using jQuery. Thanks

Comment: that is `pure javascript` ~ are you referring to the #${id} within backticks? That is a new(ish) method to use strings as variables and nothing to do with jQuery. It saves the need to escape from quotes to embed a variable

Comment: Hi @Codelate, glad  I could help. FYI: all the scripting in the snippet is plain vanilla javascript (ES20xx). See: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector. Also: https://exploringjs.com/es6/

Comment: @KooiInc, Now the coder runs well here but when I tried to implement it on VScode to the browser, it doesn't. I got the same issue. Result only flashed and never add up physically. I tried to debug and got a Reference error: "document is not defined". What could be the possible cause please. sorry for bothering you

Comment: @Codelate this code is browser related, so you can only run it _within_ a browser. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by '*...to implement it on VSCode to the browser*'

Comment: @KooiInc, yes I understand. I tried to run it in chrome browser, but it just wouldn't add the input to the list. and when I debugged it in the IDE (visual studio code), I got an error: 'document is not defined' could this be the reason its not adding the input?

Answer (score 0):

I too did a little `re-factoring` ~ aka `playing` which might perhaps be of help/interest?!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Trees in the Forest</title>
        <style>
            body, body *{ box-sizing:border-box;font-family:monospace }
            #forest{ width:100%; height:50vh;}
            .tree{
                width:50px;
                height:80px;
                margin:0.25rem; 
                background:url(https://png.pngtree.com/element_our/sm/20180527/sm_5b0b21833edb1.png);
                background-size:contain;
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                background-position:bottom;
                background-color:rgba(0,200,0,0.1)
            }
            ol{ width:100%; margin:1rem auto }
            ol > li{display:inline-block;text-align:center}
        </style>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{

                const domTarget=function(n){
                    return document.getElementById( n );
                };

                /* utility to generate new DOM elements with attributes and value */
                const create=function(t,a,p){
                    let el = ( typeof( t )=='undefined' || t==null ) ? document.createElement( 'div' ) : document.createElement( t );
                    let _arr=['innerHTML','innerText','html','text'];
                    for( let x in a ) if( a.hasOwnProperty( x ) && !~_arr.indexOf( x ) ) el.setAttribute( x, a[ x ] );
                    if( a.hasOwnProperty('innerHTML') || a.hasOwnProperty('html') ) el.innerHTML=a.innerHTML || a.html;
                    if( a.hasOwnProperty('innerText') || a.hasOwnProperty('text') ) el.innerText=a.innerText || a.text;
                    if( p!=null ) typeof( p )=='object' ? p.appendChild( el ) : document.getElementById( p ).appendChild( el );
                    return el;
                };

                /* wrapper for rebuilding the OL contents */
                const createforest=function(a,p){
                    p.innerHTML=''; // clear previous content
                    a.sort( ( x, y )=>{ return x > y ? 1 : -1 } ) // sort the array alphabetically
                    a.forEach( tree => { create( 'li',{ text:tree, 'class':'tree', 'data-tree':tree }, p ); } ); // add each tree
                };


                /* The initial collection of trees */
                let trees=[ 'spruce', 'pine', 'cedar' ];



                /* Existing DOM elements */
                let forest=domTarget('forest');
                let bttn=document.querySelector('form > input[ type="button" ]');
                let ol=create( 'ol', {}, forest );



                /* create the initial display of trees */
                createforest( trees, ol );




                /* Listen for button clicks - add new tree to the array and rebuild display */
                bttn.addEventListener( 'click', function(e){
                    let input=this.previousElementSibling;
                    if( input.value!='' ){
                        if( trees.length >= 3 ){
                            /* add to the array */
                            trees.push( input.value );

                            /* rebuild the display */
                            createforest( trees, ol );

                            /* clear the input field */
                            input.value='';
                            input.focus();
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                    alert( 'Please enter a tree name' );
                });


                /* listenen for clicks on parent container */
                ol.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
                    if( e.target!=e.currentTarget ){
                        /* remove tree from array and display */
                        let tree=e.target.dataset.tree;
                        trees.splice( trees.indexOf( tree ), 1 );
                        e.target.parentNode.removeChild( e.target );
                    }
                });
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='forest'></div>
        <form>
            <input type='text' />
            <input type='button' value='Add Tree' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```